# C# to SQL connection username issue

Tags: c#, sql

The program I am coding must be able to work on every pc. It is a form application. How can I get the username info of any pc as a parameter for my connection string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From myapplicaiton.exe.config:

```
connectionString="Data Source=myserver;Initial Catalog=myDB;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=USER_NAME;Password=USER_PASS;"
```